# Drupal Lightbox issue (not jQuery lightbox)

Tags: drupal, view, flags

I am having a issue in Flag_list module, can anyone please help me out how to put a flag list and how to view it please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The module has very good description how to do it : http://drupal.org/project/flag_lists

How to use:

- Install as usual.
- At admin/build/flags you will see a flag "fl_template." This is a default template flag provided by flag_lists. You can edit it to make changes to list messages and to assign it to node types. This
  template will be used only on types you assign.
- You can create new templates here: admin/build/flags/lists/template and apply them to other node types.
- A template can be assiged to many node types, but a node type can only have one template assigned to it.
- Enable the "list" block so that it is displayed on your content. The block will only be visible if the content is listable and the user has permission to create lists. That is, the node type must be assigned a template, or the block won't appear. Further, you should enable the link to create lists in the block's config.
- Create new lists using the link in the block.
- See your lists and listed content at user/[uid]/flags/lists